# Why do these NFAs need epsilon transitions?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

In the picture below, I'm trying to figure out why there's a need of epsilon in there and what would be the difference if we didn't put epsilon.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: I was trying to convert the regular expression (00)*(11) to an NFA. A part of the solution is the picture above but I couldn't understand why epsilon is used in order accept 11 or 00.

Comment: When folks ask for clarification, please don't just drop stuff in the comments.  Instead, edit the question.  Comments are transitory.  We want the question to be self-contained; people shouldn't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not make a difference. In fact, we don't *need* epsilon transitions, in the strict sense. Even though they can not be just left out in general, they can always be replaced by several edges using the *epsilon closure* (cf. the powerset construction).

These examples most likely stem from [Thompson's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson's_construction), a simple algorithm that creates an NFA equivalent to a given regular expression. It uses epsilon transitions to link recursively constructed subautomata together.